# Problem of small brackets in Latex

Tags: brackets

I have a problem in my script LaTeX. I write  with the biggest parentheses, brackets, accolades, but always I get too small parentheses.

In this example,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{etex} 
\RequirePackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb} 
\usepackage{oz} 
\begin{document} 
\[ \Bigg\{ A + B = C\Bigg\} \] 
\end{document}
```

using the package `oz` I get small delimiters. I use the package `oz` to get the symbol of concatenation of two sets.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Exactly why are you using `oz`? Seems to work fine if you remove the `\RequirePackage` line, i.e. no `amsmath` and friends.

Comment: It is worse than that, the package `oz` is destroying the definitions of `\bigl` etc.  Which symbol are you using for concatenation.  If it just `\circ` then it is defined without tho `oz` package.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be caused by a conflict between `amsmath` and `oz`. One solution is to load `oz` first. Some hacking is then required to make the two packages play nicely together.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@dot\dot
\usepackage{oz}
\let\oz@implies\implies
\let\oz@mod\mod
\let\oz@dot\dot
\let\implies\relax
\let\mod\relax
\let\dot\latex@dot
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\implies\oz@implies
\let\mod\oz@mod
\let\dot\oz@dot
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \Bigg\{ A + B = C\Bigg\} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: braces]

Comment: Put more simply, `oz` and `amsmath` are incompatible with each other.

Comment: @Ian Thompson: Unfortunately the problem persists for me. I used your code but it didn't work?

Comment: This is the error I got :



! LaTeX Error: Command \implies already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.308 ...mand{\implies}{\DOTSB\;\Longrightarrow\;}

Comment: @OuBaï --- the original version had a typo: `\relx` instead of `\relax`. It works for me with this corrected.